# regex for parsing request parameters

Tags: regex, pcre

I am looking for a single perl compatible regex that would parse strings of the form:

param1=value1&...&param2=value2&...

and extract values for param1 and param2 only. But

1. param2 may precede param1
2. There may be no param1 or param2
3. param1 or param2 (or both) may have empty values, i.e. param1=&...

Comment: Changed your tags from perl to pcre, as pcres only real relation to perl is the name. Outside that, there is hardly anything perl about them. Asking for a perl answer will get you a perl answer, and it /wont/ work with PCRE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755168/perl-myths/933070#933070

Added this myth to the myth factoid list.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother writing your own request parser.  Just use [`CGI.pm`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/CGI.pm).

Comment: Seconded. I went looking for an old snipped that parse query strings by hand, and found that I'd long ago converted my scripts to use CGI.pm

Comment: The problem is that it's not actually perl, it's C++. I just use perl-compatible regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

```
/[?&]([^=]+)=([^=&]+)/g
```

This will match any non = character separated by an = and put them into $1 and $2.

or...

```
my %argsHash = split(/=|&/, $args);
```

This will give you a hash with parameters and values which appears to work well, but CGI.pm is all around a better idea.

Comment: missing close paren for 2nd match group

Comment: The second [^=]+ will gobble up the ampersand and the next parameter name. Also, if you match an ampersand at the end, the [?&] at the beginning will have nothing to match the next time around.

Answer (score 1):

`/(.*?)=(.*?)&/` looping through and capturing `$1` and `$2` should work

Comment: A single . matches any one character this would work if the parameters and values are all a single character.

Comment: yeah somehow the * got lost of course I meant (.*?) question mark for lazy evaluation

Comment: Markdown bit you, * means italicise to it and it nuked it. Downvote deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for C++, consider using an existing CGI library that parses the query parameters for you instead of reinventing that sort of thing yourself.

One such library is `cgic`, a CGI library for C: http://www.boutell.com/cgic/#functions